# Android trying to put image as a ByteArray into sqlite database, getting error on put method

Tags: android, image, sqlite, arrays, put

I'm trying to enter an image into a database together with some strings, but I get the following error on my put method:

```
The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, Byte[])
```

But when I see it in tutorials, it seems to be done exactly like how I do it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
    "CREATE Table " + DATABASE_TABLE_LIST + " ( "
    + LIST_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY Autoincrement, "
    + LIST_NAME + " text NOT NULL, "
    + LIST_ADDRESS + " text NOT NULL, " 
    + LIST_IMAGE + " BLOB );";

...

public long createItem(String name, String address, Byte[] image) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(LIST_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(LIST_ADDRESS, address);
    initialValues.put(LIST_IMAGE, image);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_LIST, null, initialValues);
}
```

I guess it might have something to do with putting strings as well as the bytearray, but I wouldn't know how to solve it and can't find it through Googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange to me that you try to insert a **B** yte array. Your image data is most probably a **b** yte array. As there is no put method for arrays of Byte objects but only for arrays of the primitive data type *byte* the compiler has no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

```
DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet("your image url");  
HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);  
if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {  
  HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();  
    if ( entity != null) {  
      // insert to database  
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
      values.put(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));  
      getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: yes, that's one of the tutorials I used as a base. but I have my queries and methods that interact with the database in a separate DatabaseAdapter class. I call the createItem method in my activity class, so I don't have to rewrite those database interaction blocks of code in each different activity class I want to use it in. In my Activity class I would call something like DatabaseAdapter.createItem(String name, String address, Byte[] image);